# references to \item

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to make a reference to \item 1.1.
[image: ![enter image description here]

But instead of **1.1** it shows as **1.a**. Why?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Code (XeLatex Compiler):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage, twoside]{article}

% overfull, underfull 
\hbadness=\maxdimen
\vbadness=\maxdimen
\vfuzz=30pt
\hfuzz=30pt


%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tabto} % biblioteka do tab 
%\usepackage{tabbing}
\usepackage{parskip} % Dzięki tej bibliotece tekst, który zawiera puste linie będzie tak odwzorowany w dokumencie. Normalnie puste linie są ignorowane. 
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % XeLatex używa utf 8, więc jest to zbędne w przypadku tego kompilatora 
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabulary} % Dla bardziej zaawansowanych tabel. Zawija automatycznie tekst
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[OT4]{polski} % pakiet języka polskiego
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %pakiet do przesuwania grafiki prawo/lewo
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%pakiet do grafiki
%\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz} %pakiet do przekreślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %pakiet do kolorowania tablicy
\usepackage[margin = 2cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\makeatletter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{caption}    %for going to the top of an image when a figure reference is clicked
\usepackage[text= black, background = white , arrow = black ]{callouts} % Dodawanie odnośników na figures - parametry 
\usepackage{tikz} % Rysowanie strzałek, odnośników na figures
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % Ustawienie, dzięki któremu możemy numerować rodziały z czterema miejsca (paragraph) np. 1.1.1.1, dla pieciu zmień 4->5
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} % Ustawienie, dzięki któremu możemy numerować rodziały z czterema miejsca (paragraph) np. 1.1.1.1, dla pieciu zmień 4->5
%\usepackage{parskip} parskip = 1pt
\usepackage{multirow} % Biblioteka dla scalania wierszy tabel
%\usepackage{pbox} % Biblioteka dla dodwania nowych linii, bez dodawania nowego wiersza w tabeli 
\usepackage{nicematrix} % Biblioteki do przekraślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage{calc}% Biblioteki do przekraślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Biblioteka dla przesuwania obrazków w prawą stronę
\usepackage{enumitem} % Biblioteka dla numeracji poprzedzonej literą
\usepackage{listliketab} % Biblioteka, dzięki której można wprowadzać numerację w tabeli
\usepackage{xurl} % Biblioteka, która sprawia, że linki zawijają się 

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tasks,blindtext}
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage} % Zaczynanie rozdziału zawsze od nowej strony
\usepackage{float} % Pakiet używany w celu wymuszenia pozycjonowania tabeli/zdjęcia w miejscu wywołania
\restylefloat{table} % -||-
\usepackage{mdwlist} % pozwala na zawieszanie (suspend) i wznawianie numerowania (resume)
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Usunięcie wcięć w nowych akapitach
\usepackage{ragged2e} % bibioteka, która pozwala na wprowadzania wyrówanania do prawej i lewej 
\usepackage{tabularray} % Pakiet do tabel. M.in. do centrowania zdjęć 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % -||-
 \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth} % -||- 
\usepackage{hyperref} % %pakiet do wstawiania linków z kolorem
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{titlesec} % Pakiet pozwalający na stworzenie odległości po tytule paragrafu 
\usepackage{comment} %pakiet do dodawania komentarzy wielolinijkowych
\usepackage{caption} % Pakiet do dodawania subfigure
\usepackage{subcaption}% Pakiet do dodawania subfigure
\usepackage{verbatimbox} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% zredefiniowanie callout, tak aby strzałka miała białe tło 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\callout}[3]{%
\node [fill=\bgcol] (text) at (#1) {\scriptsize\color{\focol} #2};
\draw [white,line width=4pt,-{Latex[length=3pt 2.5 0.8]},shorten >=-4pt] (text) -- (#3);
\draw [\arcol,thick,-{Latex}] (text) -- (#3);
}
% Stworzenie countera do automatycznego numerowania wierszy w tabeli 
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

% Zmiana czcionki na Arial. 
% Uwaga! Nalezy zmienić kompilator na XeLatex
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
% ------ 

% zredefiniowanie komedy paragraph tak, by tekst pojawial sie w nowej linii
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0ex}%
   {-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex}%
   {1.5ex plus 0.2ex}%
   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

% zredefiniowanie komedy subparagraph tak, by tekst pojawial sie w nowej linii
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{0ex}%
   {-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex}%
   {1.5ex plus 0.2ex}%
   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
% ---- Dostosowywanie numeracji tak by przy używaniu wyliczenia \item uzyskać 1.1, 1.1.1 oraz 1.1.1.1
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.\arabic{enumiv}}

% Tutaj zdefiniowane są komendy i funkcje dla numerowania (B1, B1.1, A1 itd.) 
\newcounter{tabenum}  % Dodanie [tabenum] wymusza wyzerowanie tabenumm, gdy tabenum wzrosnie
\newcounter{tabenumm}[tabenum] % Dodanie [tabenumm] wymusza wyzerowanie tabenummm, gdy tabenumm wzrosnie
\newcounter{tabenummm}[tabenumm] % Dodanie [tabenumm] wymusza wyzerowanie tabenummm, gdy tabenumm wzrosnie
\newcounter{tabenummmm}[tabenummm] % Dodanie [tabenummm] wymusza wyzerowanie tabenummmm, gdy tabenumm wzrosnie

% \nextnum - numeracja 1. itd.
% \nextnumm - numeracja 1.1 itd.
% \nextnummm - numeracja 1.1.1 itd.
% \nextnummmm - numeracja 1.1.1.1 itd. 
\newcommand{\nextnum}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum} 
\newcommand{\nextnumm}{\refstepcounter{tabenumm}\thetabenumm}
\newcommand{\nextnummm}{\refstepcounter{tabenummm}\thetabenummm}
\newcommand{\nextnummmm}{\refstepcounter{tabenummmm}\thetabenummmm}

% Funkcja wyliczenia
\newcommand{\wyliczenie}[1]
{
\storestyleof {enumerate}
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\setcounter{tabenumm}{0} 
\setcounter{tabenummm}{0}
\setcounter{tabenummmm}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetabenum}{#1\arabic{tabenum}.} % #1 to argument funkcji, który będziemy podawać przy wywołaniu. Na przykład A, B, C. Zależy jak chcemy by wyglądała nasza numeracja. Jeśli nie podamy nic, to numeracja będzie zaczynała się bez litery. 
\renewcommand{\thetabenumm}{\thetabenum\arabic{tabenumm}}
\renewcommand{\thetabenummm}{\thetabenumm.\arabic{tabenummm}}
\renewcommand{\thetabenummmm}{\thetabenummm.\arabic{tabenummmm}} 
}


% Ustalenie koloru odnośników / hyperlinków 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, % kolor linków
    linkcolor=black, % kolor linków wewnętrznych / odnośników
    filecolor=magenta,   % kolor linków do lokalnych plików   
    urlcolor=cyan, % kolor linków do stron internetowych
    }

% Dodanie logo w nagłówku po stronie 
% LO - lewej dla stron niepatrzystych (LEFT ODD)
% RE - prawej dla stron parzystych (RIGHT EVEN)

% Dodanie numeru strony (/thepage) w stopce, po stronie:
% LO - lewej dla stron patrzystych (LEFT EVEN)
% RE - prawej dla stron nieparzystych (RIGHT ODD)

% ----------- Strona tytułowa ------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{załączniki}
\author{aniaskubis }
\date{November 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Załączniki}\label{sec:Zalaczniki}
\ref{sec:Zal_BS1}

\subsection{Załączniki występujące tylko w wersji elektronicznej}\label{sec:Zalaczniki_Elektroniczne}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{sec:Zalaczniki_Rexroth} \textbf{Rexroth} (A Bosch Company)  
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item\label{sec:Zal_BS1} \textbf{Odcinek taśmy BS 1} Instrukcja montażu numer: 3 842 563 814/2021-11
        \item\label{sec:Zal_EQ2T} \textbf{Elektryczny transport EQ 2/T} Instrukcja montażu numer: MTPL 515 431/2010-11
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) **minimal** example please, most of the packages in this example are not relevant to this problem. (2) never show images of code, no-one wants to retype that in order to test it. (3) Make your example complete, you have only posted a preamble.

Comment: As I said make your example **minimal** no-one wants to debug all that irrelevant code. Please reduce it down to what is relevant to show the problem

Comment: I agree with daleif, but my guess is that your problem is when you renewcommand `\labelenum`.  It might be better to use the `enumitem` package to take care of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referencing an enumeration item with redefined \labelenumi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/referencing-an-enumeration-item-with-redefined-labelenumi)

Comment: Here is the most simple of examples: `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\begin{document}
ref: \ref{item:level1.1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{item:level1} level 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item\label{item:level1.1} level 1.1
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`. As @Teepeemm says the problems comes from `\labelenum`

Comment: Please don't vote to close questions before OPs have a chance to improve them!

Comment: @cfr Why? It will still be a duplicate. What does it matter if it is linked to the dupe before or after editing?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Because this isn't a duplicate as far as I can tell. At least, it certainly is not a duplicate of the question you linked. That one asks how to get e.g. '1.a.' rather than '1.1', whereas this one wants to get '1.1' and is getting '1.a'. That's also clear in the image posted: it is the '1a' which needs changing.

Comment: @cfr The dupe both shows how to use the enumitem package to change the references as well as how to redefine `\labelenumi`.  Given that the OP already uses `\arabic{...}` in multiple places in their code, I trust that they can exchange `\alph` with the format they wish to use.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Much of the preamble is clearly the result of blind copy-pasting. If the OP understood the principle underlying that question is the same as here, I doubt the question would need asking. On the face of it 'I'm getting 1a and I want 1.1' is very different from 'I'm getting 1.1 and want 1a'.

Answer (score 1):

*Justification for answering: Although the underlying issue in the proposed duplicate may be the same, it may be far from obvious that 'I'm getting "a" and want "1"' requires the same solution as 'I'm getting "1" and want "a"', especially since the 'a' in this case is nested at a deeper level not relevant to that question. Nothing in the alleged duplicate addresses configuring labels for different levels using `enumitem` or otherwise, but that's crucial here. Arabic numerals are already default at the top level.*

---

Here's an example showing how to configure each level of `enumerate` using `enumitem`. We don't need to configure the top level as the default is fine.

```
\setlist[2,enumerate]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[3,enumerate]{label=\theenumii.\arabic*}
\setlist[4,enumerate]{label=\theenumiii.\arabic*}
```

Each level utilises the label defined for the previous one, which makes it easier to alter the format if required later. We can change the appearance of all labels and references by editing only the configurations of the levels we want to change.

For example, if we decided we wanted large Roman numerals for our top level we could add

```
\setlist[1,enumerate]{\Roman*.}
```

and the format of labels for all levels will change accordingly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[T1,OT4]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem} % Biblioteka dla numeracji poprzedzonej literą

\setlist[2,enumerate]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[3,enumerate]{label=\theenumii.\arabic*}
\setlist[4,enumerate]{label=\theenumiii.\arabic*}
\begin{document}

\section{Załączniki}\label{sec:Zalaczniki}
\ref{sec:Zal_BS1}

\subsection{Załączniki występujące tylko w wersji elektronicznej}\label{sec:Zalaczniki_Elektroniczne}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{sec:Zalaczniki_Rexroth} \textbf{Rexroth} (A Bosch Company)  
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{sec:Zal_BS1} \textbf{Odcinek taśmy BS 1} Instrukcja montażu numer: 3 842 563 814/2021-11
    \item\label{sec:Zal_EQ2T} \textbf{Elektryczny transport EQ 2/T} Instrukcja montażu numer: MTPL 515 431/2010-11
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: matching reference to label]